# Columns order in ListGrid Smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

How can I programmatically change the order of columns in ListGrid? I have search for an appropriate method in javadoc but found nothing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [setViewState](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html) method and this [example](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_preferences) that saves and restores grid preferences (including column order). So in short, you are interested in getting viewState string from ListGrid data and using it. Remember to redraw grid after setting new viewState.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is what I'm searching for.

Comment: Try it and if it works as you wanted mark this as correct answer :)